# Second To HH:MM:SS conversion is incorrect after 100 hrs in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to convert second format to `hh:mm:ss` format .

After 360000 sec (100 hrs) the `hh:mm:ss` format is reset to 00:00:00

This is the code I am using :

```
create table #test (seconds bigint)

insert into #test values ('359999')

SELECT  
    seconds,
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST((seconds / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS [HH:MM:SS] 
FROM 
    #test
```

Result :

```
Total_HandleTime_Sale     HH:MM:SS
360000                    00:00:00
```

But for my application I need the output as :

```
Total_HandleTime_Sale     HH:MM:SS
360000                    100:00:00
```

Comment: Replace `RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2)` with `RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR),(CASE LEN(CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR)) > 2 THEN LEN(CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR)) ELSE 2 END)`

Comment: insert into #test values ('360000')

Answer (score 2):

The `RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2)` trims the `1` from the `100` value - so you need to test if the value is smaller then 100 or bigger then 99.

```
create table #test
(seconds bigint)

insert into #test values (360000), (359999)

SELECT  seconds,
        CASE WHEN seconds / 3600 < 100 THEN
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2)
        ELSE
            RIGHT('000' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR),3)
        END + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((seconds / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
as [HH:MM:SS] FROM #test

drop table #test
```

Result :

```
seconds              HH:MM:SS
-------------------- ---------
360000               100:00:00
359999               99:59:59
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `varchar` with no length specifier in SQL Server.  This is dangerous, because the default length varies by context.

In your expression, you have:

```
RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

Well, this is taking exactly two characters.  So "'100'" --> "'00'".

Here is one way to fix the expression:

```
SELECT seconds,
       (RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR(255)), 3) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((seconds / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR(255)), 2) + ':'  + 
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds % 60 AS VARCHAR(255)), 2)
       ) as [HH:MM:SS]
FROM #test;
```

However, this will give the results as HHHH:MM:SS.  And, you'll have the same problem at 1000 hours.  So, this may be what you want:

```
SELECT seconds,
       ((CASE WHEN seconds < 36000
              THEN RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR(255)), 2)
              ELSE CAST(seconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR(255))
          END) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((seconds / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR(255)), 2) + ':'  + 
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(seconds % 60 AS VARCHAR(255)), 2)
       ) as [HH:MM:SS]
FROM #test;
```

This will only add extra digits to the hours when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @seco int
set @seco=370000
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,@seco/60/60)+':'+RIGHT('00'+convert(varchar,@seco/60%60),2)+':'+RIGHT('00'+convert(varchar,@seco%60),2)
```